# Undefined Symbols in wxWidgets project in Xcode

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to configure a project in Xcode, using wxWidgets-2.9.4, on Mac OS X 10.8.3. I configured wxWidgets with the following options:

```
./configure --enable-debug --disable-shared --enable-unicode --with-osx_cocoa --enable-monolithic
```

and then compiled the library successfully. All the demos works fine.

I configured my project with the flags obtained using wx-config. In particular:

```
./wx-config --libs
-L/wxWidgets/wxWidgets-2.9.4/build-release/lib   -framework IOKit -framework Carbon -   framework Cocoa -framework AudioToolbox -framework System -framework OpenGL /wxWidgets/wxWidgets-2.9.4/build-release/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau-2.9.a -framework WebKit -lwxregexu-2.9 -lwxtiff-2.9 -lwxjpeg-2.9 -lwxpng-2.9 -lz -lpthread

./wx-config --cxxflags
-I/wxWidgets/wxWidgets-2.9.4/build-release/lib/wx/include/osx_cocoa-unicode-static-2.9 -  I/wxWidgets/wxWidgets-2.9.4/include -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D__WXMAC__ -D__WXOSX__ -D__WXOSX_COCOA__
```

When I try to build my project I get many Undefined symbols:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"wxOnAssert(char const*, int, char const*, char const*, wchar_t const*)", referenced from:
  wxMouseState::ButtonIsDown(wxMouseButton) const   in Canvas.o
  wxControlContainerBase::SetContainerWindow(wxWindow*)       in Canvas.o
  wxCloseEvent::Veto(bool)  in GeoTecDocView.o
  wxMouseState::ButtonIsDown(wxMouseButton) const   in GeoTecDocView.o
  wxBufferedDC::InitCommon(wxDC*, int)   in GeoTecDocView.o
  wxBoxSizer::wxBoxSizer(int)in GeoTecDocView.o
  wxArrayString::Item(unsigned long)in GeoTecWxDoc.o
  ...
  "wxOnAssert(char const*, int, char const*, char const*, char const*)", referenced from:
  wxEventFunctorMethod<wxEventTypeTag<wxCommandEvent>, wxEvtHandler, wxEvent, wxEvtHandler>::operator()(wxEvtHandler*, wxEvent&)in DocManager.o
  wxEventFunctorMethod<wxEventTypeTag<wxCommandEvent>, wxEvtHandler, wxEvent, wxEvtHandler>::wxEventFunctorMethod(void (wxEvtHandler::*)(wxEvent&), wxEvtHandler*)in DocManager.o
  wxEventTableEntryBase::wxEventTableEntryBase(int, int, wxEventFunctor*, wxObject*)in DocManager.o
  wxEventFunctorMethod<wxEventTypeTag<wxCommandEvent>, wxEvtHandler, wxEvent, wxEvtHandler>::operator()(wxEvtHandler*, wxEvent&)in GeoTecApp.o
  wxEventFunctorMethod<wxEventTypeTag<wxCommandEvent>, wxEvtHandler, wxEvent, wxEvtHandler>::wxEventFunctorMethod(void (wxEvtHandler::*)(wxEvent&), wxEvtHandler*)in GeoTecApp.o
  wxEventTableEntryBase::wxEventTableEntryBase(int, int, wxEventFunctor*, wxObject*)in GeoTecApp.o
  wxEventFunctorMethod<wxEventTypeTag<wxKeyEvent>, wxEvtHandler, wxEvent, wxEvtHandler>::operator()(wxEvtHandler*, wxEvent&)in GeoTecDocView.o
  ...
  "wxMessageBox(wxString const&, wxString const&, long, wxWindow*, int, int)", referenced from:
  GeoTecMainFrame::OnCancellaTutti(wxCommandEvent&)        in GeoTecDocView.o
  GeoTecMainFrame::OnCancellaLineaCedimenti(wxCommandEvent&)        in GeoTecDocView.o
  GeoTecMainFrame::OnRicalcolaOra(wxCommandEvent&)        in GeoTecDocView.o
  GeoTecMainFrame::AggiornaFinestre()       in GeoTecDocView.o
  GeoTecMainFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent&)       in GeoTecDocView.o
  GeoTecMainFrame::OnRemoveObject(GTGraphicObject*)        in GeoTecDocView.o
  StratigrafiaDialog::Validate()      in GTDialogs.o
  ...
  "wxFileSelector(wxString const&, wxString const&, wxString const&, wxString const&, wxString const&, int, wxWindow*, int, int)", referenced from:
  GeoTecMainFrame::OnImporta(wxCommandEvent&)       in GeoTecDocView.o
  "wxGet_wxConvLibcPtr()", referenced from:
  wxGet_wxConvLibc()     in Canvas.o
  wxGet_wxConvLibc()     in GeoTecApp.o
  wxGet_wxConvLibc()     in GeoTecDocView.o
  wxGet_wxConvLibc()     in GeoTecWxDoc.o
  wxGet_wxConvLibc()     in GlobalParameters.o
  wxGet_wxConvLibc()     in GTDialogs.o
  wxGet_wxConvLibc()     in GTPrint.o
  ...
  "wxBell()", referenced from:
  StrisciaIndefinitaDialog::Calcola(wxCommandEvent&)       in GTDialogs.o
  NumberValidator::OnChar(wxKeyEvent&)       in Validators.o
  IntValidator::OnChar(wxKeyEvent&)       in Validators.o
  "wxEntry(int&, char**)", referenced from:
  _main in GeoTecApp.o
  "wxCheckBox::Create(wxWindow*, int, wxString const&, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long, wxValidator const&, wxString const&)", referenced from:
  wxCheckBox::wxCheckBox(wxWindow*, int, wxString const&, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long, wxValidator const&, wxString const&)in GTDialogs.o
  "wxClientDC::wxClientDC(wxWindow*)", referenced from:
  Canvas::OnMouseMove(wxMouseEvent&)       in Canvas.o
  Canvas::OnMouseLeftUp(wxMouseEvent&)       in Canvas.o
  GeoTecCanvas::OnMouseMove(wxMouseEvent&)        in GeoTecDocView.o
  GeoTecCanvas::OnMouseLeftUp(wxMouseEvent&)        in GeoTecDocView.o
  GeoTecCanvas::OnMouseLeftDown(wxMouseEvent&)        in GeoTecDocView.o
  GeoTecCanvas::OnMouseDClick(wxMouseEvent&)        in GeoTecDocView.o
  RiepilogoStratigrafieCanvas::OnMouseLeftDown(wxMouseEvent&)        in RiepilogoStratigrafieView.o
  ...
  "wxDocument::LoadObject(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
  GeoTecWxDoc::LoadObject(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)in GeoTecWxDoc.o
  "wxDocument::RemoveView(wxView*)", referenced from:
  vtable for GeoTecWxDocin GeoTecWxDoc.o
  "wxDocument::SaveObject(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
  GeoTecWxDoc::SaveObject(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)in GeoTecWxDoc.o
 "wxDocument::SetFilename(wxString const&, bool)", referenced from:
  GeoTecWxDoc::SaveAs()      in GeoTecWxDoc.o
 "wxDocument::ms_classInfo", referenced from:
  __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in GeoTecWxDoc.o
 "wxDocument::NotifyClosing()", referenced from:
  vtable for GeoTecWxDocin GeoTecWxDoc.o
```

and lots more.

The project works fine if I use wxMac-2.8.12, but I've got some graphical issues, so I would like to try the new version.

Thanks for any help.
Eve

Answer (score 0):

You've probably built wxWidgets for x86 only. At any rate, you definitely built it for a single architecture while your Xcode project is probably set up to build for both x86 and x86_64.

If you do need 64 bit version of your application, you should reconfigure wxWidgets with `--enable-universal_binary=x86,x86_64` options. But I'd advise to just build Xcode project in 32 bits only (i.e. just for x86), at least during development.

Comment: Thank you VZ. Actually I had already tried. Actually I get the same errors: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "wxOnAssert(char const*, int, char const*, char const*, wchar_t const*)", referenced from:
     and so on

Comment: Unless you used `--disable-debug` when configuring, `wxOnAssert()` must be there. So the only other possibility is that you are not linking against the library you built but some other, older, version.

Comment: I have no idea why, but I started again with a new project and everything works now :)
Thanks!